# Disjunction and membership in python

Tags: python, boolean, membership, disjunction

When I try this code:

```
a = ['b']

if 'i' or 'j' in a:
    print('Yes!')
else:
    print('No!')
```

The output is 'Yes!'. Flake8 and python do not complain about an error or bad form.

What exactly happens when the code runs? Why does `'i' or 'j' in a` evaluate as true?

Comment: `'i' or 'j'` is evaluated too true so `Yes` is shown. Looking for a duplicate to mark.

Comment: @0stone0 No, `i` evaluated to `True`; the other expression `'j' in a` isn't evaluated at all. `in` has higher precedence than `or`

Comment: If `'i' or 'j'` evaluated to true, then `True in a` would have been false and `No!` would have been printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the statement `i` evaluates to `True`, which means that the statement is then: `True or 'j' in a`. This is always true and your result will be always 'Yes!'.

You can use something like this to check if one of the values is in your list:

```
a = ['b']
chars_to_check = ['i', 'j']

filtered_list = [i for i in a if i in chars_to_check]

if len(filtered_list)>0:
    print('Yes!')
else:
    print('No!')
```

The example is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/740287/7947994), where people also posted more efficient or shorter solutions to your problem. The solution I like the most would be this one:

```
a = ['b']
if {'i','j'} & set(a):
    print('Yes!')
else:
    print('No!')
```

EDIT: I think now I understand the question.

First of all python sees that you have a `or` in your if statement. This means the first expression (in your case `'i'`) is evaluated first. If the first expression is `True`, the whole statement is `True` and the second expression is not even evaluated. The evaluation order of `or` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16201362/7947994) for example.

Now to why the first expression is always `True`. Python automatically evaluates all objects not only `boolean` values. For this the objects can for example contain a function `__bool__()` that gives back the `boolean` value of an object. The object in your case is a single character `'i'`, which evaluates to `True`. The reason is that it is defined that the boolean value of a string is always `True` except for the empty string (`''`). Here you can see an example of the evaluation:

```
print(bool('i')) # True
print(bool('')) # False
```

An answer that shows which objects are considered `False` and which are considered `True` can you find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237697/7947994).

Comment: Many thanks! Your answers clarified the path for further analysis :)

Comment: No problem. Just looked at it again and the correct solution for your particular case is to use `if 'i' in a or 'j' in a:`. The other things are only more complicated. The thing to remember is that the `or` divides the statement into two and evaluates the sub-statements. In your case, the first sub-statement made no sense and therefore the `if` evaluated always to `True`.

Comment: Thanks JANO, my real question is how come that the if-statement gets at True-value in this particular setting. That is, how does Python handle it, syntactically and in execution?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. Please see my edit.

Comment: So, as I understand it at the moment from your and chepners' comment: " 'j' in a" is treated as a unit which makes Python choose a boolean value for the resting part of the disjunction?

Comment: Yes " 'j' in a " is one unit and the other unit is only " 'i' ". For better understanding, you can also use parentheses, which is valid Python: `if (('i) or ('j' in a)):`. In order to evaluate the `or` the two units have to be evaluated. Python takes a shortcut here and only evaluates the first unit as it then already knows that one of both sides is `True`.

Comment: My happy thanks!